# When was the Bachelor degree of Occupational Therapy introduced in Australia?

Tags: bachelor, academic-history, australia

Sounds like a simple question, but despite a few hours of searching, I couldn't find the answer.

I would also like to know what qualification was required beforehand in order to work in that profession?

Comment: Experience probably - grew out of the general field as the need became apparent

Comment: I would suspect that a government ministry of education would have such an answer. I wouldn't know the precise name of the ministry, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The government board wasn't really helpful, but I found the answer:

> For a few years there had been a combined Physiotherapy/ Occupational
>   Therapy Degree course at The University of Queensland. In 1955 the
>   Occupational Therapy three year Diploma course was introduced.

Source: http://www.occupationaltherapyboard.gov.au/documents/default.aspx?record=WD12%2f8399&dbid=AP&chksum=SfMd1xjsN%2f1k47blbbm7MA%3d%3d